# Cloudformation stack CREATE_FAILED for ApiGateway::Method with no status reason

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway

[image]

If I remove the RestAPI + related resources, the stack succeeds. I'm not sure how to get an error message to see why it is failing with this configuration.

Here's the JSON for the resources that are failing:

```
{
   "RestAPI":{
      "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
      "Properties":{
         "Name":"FD-API"
      }
   },
   "RestAPIResourceFDImage":{
      "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Resource",
      "Properties":{
         "RestApiId":{
            "Ref":"RestAPI"
         },
         "ParentId":{
            "Fn::GetAtt":[
               "RestAPI",
               "RootResourceId"
            ]
         },
         "PathPart":"{image}"
      },
     "DependsOn": ["RestAPI"]
   },
   "RestAPIMethodGetProperties":{
      "Type":"AWS::ApiGateway::Method",
      "Properties":{
         "AuthorizationType":"NONE",
         "ResourceId":{
            "Ref":"RestAPIResourceFDImage"
         },
         "HttpMethod":"GET",
         "Integration":{
            "Type":"AWS",
            "Credentials": {
                "Fn::GetAtt": [
                    "RoleFDApiGateway",
                    "Arn"
                ]
            },
            "IntegrationHttpMethod":"POST",
            "PassthroughBehavior": "NEVER",
            "Uri":{
               "Fn::Join":[
                  "",
                  [
                     "arn:aws:apigateway:",
                     {
                        "Ref":"AWS::Region"
                     },
                     ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/",
                     {
                        "Fn::GetAtt":[
                           "FunctionFDLambda",
                           "Arn"
                        ]
                     },
                     "/invocations"
                  ]
               ]
            },
            "RequestTemplates": {
                "application/json": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "{ \"key\": \"$input.params('image')\", \"bucket\": \"",
                            {
                                "Ref": "FDBucket"
                            },
                            "\" }"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
         }
        },
        "DependsOn": ["RestAPIResourceFDImage"]
   },
   "ReatAPIDeploymentFD": {
        "Type": "AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment",
        "Properties": {
            "RestApiId": {"Ref": "RestAPI"},
            "StageName": "v1"
        },
        "DependsOn": ["RestAPIMethodGetProperties"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `RestAPIMethodGetProperties` look OK

Comment: @kixorz straingly it is failing with no reason given. I added a screenshot in the question